# Multiple Stacked Area datasets in JFreechart

Tags: jfreechart

I am using JFreechart and I'm trying to get what would be similar to the `XYDifferenceRenderer` but for a `CategoryPlot`.  Issue I am running into is being able to plot multiple `StackedAreaRenderer`s on the same plot.  The following has one StackedArea that looks like it is floating.  This is what I'm wanting.

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.util.List;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.AxisLocation;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryLabelPositions;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.AreaRendererEndType;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.StackedAreaRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

/**
 *
 * @author buxk
 */
public class DifferenceWithCategories extends ApplicationFrame{


    public DifferenceWithCategories(String title){
        super(title);

        final JFreeChart chart = createChart();

        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,270));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);

    }

    /**
     * Returns a sample dataset.
     *
     * @return The dataset.
     */
    private CategoryDataset createDataset1() {

        // row keys...
        String series1 = "First";

        // column keys...
        String category1 = "Category 1";
        String category2 = "Category 2";
        String category3 = "Category 3";
        String category4 = "Category 4";
        String category5 = "Category 5";

        // create the dataset...
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        dataset.addValue(4.0, series1, category1);
        dataset.addValue(4.0, series1, category2);
        dataset.addValue(3.0, series1, category3);
        dataset.addValue(5.0, series1, category4);
        dataset.addValue(5.0, series1, category5);

        return dataset;
    }


    /**
     * Returns a sample dataset.
     *
     * @return The dataset.
     */
    private CategoryDataset createDataset2() {

        // row keys...
        String series2 = "Second";

        // column keys...
        String category1 = "Category 1";
        String category2 = "Category 2";
        String category3 = "Category 3";
        String category4 = "Category 4";
        String category5 = "Category 5";

        // create the dataset...
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        dataset.addValue(5.0, series2, category1);
        dataset.addValue(7.0, series2, category2);
        dataset.addValue(6.0, series2, category3);
        dataset.addValue(8.0, series2, category4);
        dataset.addValue(6.0, series2, category5);

        return dataset;
    }


    /**
     * Returns a sample dataset.
     *
     * @return The dataset.
     */
    private CategoryDataset createDataset3() {

        // row keys...
        String series3 = "Third";

        // column keys...
        String category1 = "Category 1";
        String category2 = "Category 2";
        String category3 = "Category 3";
        String category4 = "Category 4";
        String category5 = "Category 5";

        // create the dataset...
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        dataset.addValue(1.0, series3, category1);
        dataset.addValue(3.0, series3, category2);
        dataset.addValue(2.0, series3, category3);
        dataset.addValue(3.0, series3, category4);
        dataset.addValue(4.0, series3, category5);

        return dataset;
    }

    private CategoryDataset merge4StackedDataset(CategoryDataset d1, CategoryDataset d2){

        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        List<Comparable> columnKeys = d1.getColumnKeys();
        List<Comparable> d1RowKeys = d1.getRowKeys();
        List<Comparable> d2RowKeys = d2.getRowKeys();
        double minValue, maxValue;
        for (Comparable columnKey : columnKeys) {
            for (Comparable rowKey : d1RowKeys) {
                for (Comparable d2RowKey : d2RowKeys) {
                    minValue = Math.min(d1.getValue(rowKey, columnKey).doubleValue(),d2.getValue(d2RowKey, columnKey).doubleValue());
                    maxValue = Math.max(d1.getValue(rowKey, columnKey).doubleValue(),d2.getValue(d2RowKey, columnKey).doubleValue());
                    dataset.addValue(minValue, rowKey, columnKey);
                    dataset.addValue(maxValue - minValue, d2RowKey, columnKey);
//                    dataset.addValue(d2.getValue(d2RowKey, columnKey).doubleValue(), d2RowKey, columnKey);
                }
            }

        }

        return dataset;
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart() {

        CategoryDataset dataset1 = merge4StackedDataset(createDataset1(), createDataset2());
        CategoryDataset dataset2 = merge4StackedDataset(createDataset1(), createDataset3());

        //create chart with empty dataset
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createAreaChart(
                "Testing",
                "Categories",
                "Values",
                dataset1,
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,  // legend
                true,  // tool tips
                false  // URLs
        );

        //make the chart have a white background
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

        //get the chart's plot
        final CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();

        //color the plot
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

        //make a stacked area renderer for the first dataset
        final StackedAreaRenderer renderer1 = new StackedAreaRenderer();
        renderer1.setEndType(AreaRendererEndType.LEVEL);
        renderer1.setDefaultToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator());

        //turn off the first data set that lets the stack float
        renderer1.setSeriesPaint(0, new Color(Color.blue.getRed(), Color.blue.getGreen(), Color.blue.getBlue(), 0));
        renderer1.setSeriesVisibleInLegend(0, false);

        plot.setRenderer(0, renderer1);
        plot.setRenderer(1, renderer1);


//        plot.setDataset(2, dataset2);
//        final StackedAreaRenderer renderer2 = new StackedAreaRenderer();
//        renderer2.setEndType(AreaRendererEndType.LEVEL);
//        renderer2.setDefaultToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator());
//        renderer2.setSeriesPaint(2, new Color(Color.green.getRed(), Color.green.getGreen(), Color.green.getBlue(), 0));
//        renderer2.setSeriesVisibleInLegend(2, false);
//        renderer1.setSeriesPaint(2, new Color(Color.green.getRed(), Color.green.getGreen(), Color.green.getBlue(), 0));
//        renderer1.setSeriesPaint(3, new Color(Color.black.getRed(), Color.black.getGreen(), Color.black.getBlue(), 255));
//        renderer1.setSeriesVisibleInLegend(2, false);
//        plot.setRenderer(2, renderer2);
//        plot.setRenderer(3, renderer2);
//        plot.setRenderer(2, renderer1);
//        plot.setRenderer(3, renderer1);

        plot.setDomainAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_RIGHT);
        plot.getDomainAxis().setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.DOWN_45);
        plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
        plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);

        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final DifferenceWithCategories demo = new DifferenceWithCategories("Diference With Categories");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

version 1
If I uncomment the sections of code for `dataset2` and `renderer2` then I get some weird results where, I have three areas present and three items listed in the legend.

version 2
If I uncomment the sections of code for `dataset2` and `renderer1` the I get what I think is close to what I want but, the area for both is red and the legend on both is `Second` which is not present for `dataset2`.

Does anyone know how I can get the coloring of version 1 but the area sets of version 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to get what I'm looking for.  The issue comes from the renderer needing to know the index of the datasets relative to itself vs index of the datasets relative to the plot.
So it was fixed with a second renderer using dataset indexing relative to itself when the renderer is added to the plot.

## Code with expected outputs:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.util.List;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.AxisLocation;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryLabelPositions;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.AreaRendererEndType;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.StackedAreaRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

/**
 *
 * @author lemming622
 */
public class DifferenceWithCategories extends ApplicationFrame{


    public DifferenceWithCategories(String title){
        super(title);

        final JFreeChart chart = createChart();

        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,270));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);

    }

    /**
     * Returns a sample dataset.
     *
     * @return The dataset.
     */
    private CategoryDataset createDataset1() {

        // row keys...
        String series1 = "First";

        // column keys...
        String category1 = "Category 1";
        String category2 = "Category 2";
        String category3 = "Category 3";
        String category4 = "Category 4";
        String category5 = "Category 5";

        // create the dataset...
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        dataset.addValue(4.0, series1, category1);
        dataset.addValue(4.0, series1, category2);
        dataset.addValue(3.0, series1, category3);
        dataset.addValue(5.0, series1, category4);
        dataset.addValue(5.0, series1, category5);

        return dataset;
    }


    /**
     * Returns a sample dataset.
     *
     * @return The dataset.
     */
    private CategoryDataset createDataset2() {

        // row keys...
        String series2 = "Second";

        // column keys...
        String category1 = "Category 1";
        String category2 = "Category 2";
        String category3 = "Category 3";
        String category4 = "Category 4";
        String category5 = "Category 5";

        // create the dataset...
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        dataset.addValue(5.0, series2, category1);
        dataset.addValue(7.0, series2, category2);
        dataset.addValue(6.0, series2, category3);
        dataset.addValue(8.0, series2, category4);
        dataset.addValue(6.0, series2, category5);

        return dataset;
    }


    /**
     * Returns a sample dataset.
     *
     * @return The dataset.
     */
    private CategoryDataset createDataset3() {

        // row keys...
        String series3 = "Third";

        // column keys...
        String category1 = "Category 1";
        String category2 = "Category 2";
        String category3 = "Category 3";
        String category4 = "Category 4";
        String category5 = "Category 5";

        // create the dataset...
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        dataset.addValue(1.0, series3, category1);
        dataset.addValue(3.0, series3, category2);
        dataset.addValue(2.0, series3, category3);
        dataset.addValue(3.0, series3, category4);
        dataset.addValue(4.0, series3, category5);

        return dataset;
    }

    private CategoryDataset merge4StackedDataset(CategoryDataset d1, CategoryDataset d2){

        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        List<Comparable> columnKeys = d1.getColumnKeys();
        List<Comparable> d1RowKeys = d1.getRowKeys();
        List<Comparable> d2RowKeys = d2.getRowKeys();
        double minValue, maxValue;
        for (Comparable columnKey : columnKeys) {
            for (Comparable rowKey : d1RowKeys) {
                for (Comparable d2RowKey : d2RowKeys) {
                    minValue = Math.min(d1.getValue(rowKey, columnKey).doubleValue(),d2.getValue(d2RowKey, columnKey).doubleValue());
                    maxValue = Math.max(d1.getValue(rowKey, columnKey).doubleValue(),d2.getValue(d2RowKey, columnKey).doubleValue());
                    dataset.addValue(minValue, rowKey, columnKey);
                    dataset.addValue(maxValue - minValue, d2RowKey, columnKey);
//                    dataset.addValue(d2.getValue(d2RowKey, columnKey).doubleValue(), d2RowKey, columnKey);
                }
            }

        }

        return dataset;
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart() {

        CategoryDataset dataset1 = merge4StackedDataset(createDataset1(), createDataset2());
        CategoryDataset dataset2 = merge4StackedDataset(createDataset1(), createDataset3());

        //create chart with empty dataset
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createAreaChart(
                "Testing",
                "Categories",
                "Values",
                dataset1,
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,  // legend
                true,  // tool tips
                false  // URLs
        );

        //make the chart have a white background
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

        //get the chart's plot
        final CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();

        //color the plot
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

        //make a stacked area renderer for the first dataset
        final StackedAreaRenderer renderer1 = new StackedAreaRenderer();
        renderer1.setEndType(AreaRendererEndType.LEVEL);
        renderer1.setDefaultToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator());

        //turn off the first data set that lets the stack float
        renderer1.setSeriesPaint(0, new Color(Color.blue.getRed(), Color.blue.getGreen(), Color.blue.getBlue(), 0));
        renderer1.setSeriesVisibleInLegend(0, false);

        plot.setRenderer(0, renderer1);
        plot.setRenderer(1, renderer1);


        plot.setDataset(2, dataset2);
        final StackedAreaRenderer renderer2 = new StackedAreaRenderer();
        renderer2.setEndType(AreaRendererEndType.LEVEL);
        renderer2.setDefaultToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator());
        renderer2.setSeriesPaint(0, new Color(Color.green.getRed(), Color.green.getGreen(), Color.green.getBlue(), 0));
        renderer2.setSeriesVisibleInLegend(0, false);
        plot.setRenderer(2, renderer2);
        plot.setRenderer(3, renderer2);

        plot.setDomainAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_RIGHT);
        plot.getDomainAxis().setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.DOWN_45);
        plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
        plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);

        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final DifferenceWithCategories demo = new DifferenceWithCategories("Diference With Categories");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```